# Find the maximum XOR of two numbers in a growing array of integers

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, xor

Random integers are added to an array. Each time an integer is added, the maximum XOR of any two numbers from the array of all previous numbers should be output.

For example:
Input: `3 2 5 2`
Output: `0 1 7 7`

I was able to come up with a simple algorithm of complexity O((n^2) / 2). Is there a faster approach?

I know there are approaches with complexity O(n*log(n)) and even O(n) for a static array.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-xor-of-two-numbers-in-an-array/

But is there any way to apply them to this problem?

Comment: The trie approach from the article you linked should also be able to generate intermediate results